# Reading a dxf file using Streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit, ezdxf

I'm trying to use Streamlit to create an app that reads a .dxf file using ezdxf modifies it and allows a the user to download the modified file. What I'm having trouble with is getting ezdxf to read the uploaded file.

The error i'm getting from Streamlit is:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

With a traceback of:

```py
File "/Users/Username/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/Users/Username/pythonProject/Adjust_thickness_app.py", line 53, in <module>
    doc = ezdxf.readfile(uploaded_file)
File "/Users/Username/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ezdxf/filemanagement.py", line 137, in readfile
    if is_binary_dxf_file(filename):
File "/Users/Username/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ezdxf/lldxf/validator.py", line 316, in is_binary_dxf_file
    with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
```

I've tried various methods of parse the file once its been uploaded. According to what I understand from the documentation I should be able to use the file like normal once it's been uploaded using:

```py
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a .dxf file",type=['dxf'])
```

When I try to call it later in the script using:

```
doc = ezdxf.readfile(uploaded_file)
```

it throws the error.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is where your error is coming from `with open(filename, "rb") as fp:` and not from the code you shared. You need to make sure that `filename` is holding the right `path` of your file. **Note:** `st.file_uploader` has nothing to do with `FileNotFoundError:`